# Прямой доступ к оборудованию

Tags: c++, c

Хотел бы узнать: есть ли в `с++` или в `с` прямой доступ к оборудованию? То есть, могу ли я только силами `с++` обрабатывать данные с мышки, к примеру? Могу ли я работать с видеопамятью?

Comment: Можете конечно, если операционная система позволит. А так сейчас обычно сами ОС на C и пишут

Comment: @Mike, можно какие-нибудь ссылочки? Может литература есть по этой теме?

Comment: Вообще да, но все эти прелести на KernelMode. Стандартный язык для драйверов это С, но на С++ тоже пишут.

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик Вы для начала с операционной системой определитесь. потом вам надо будет изучать уже ее API. И решать зачем оно вам надо, может придется драйвер писать или что то другое пространства ядра. Можете посмотреть исходники linux, там на C почти вся работа с оборудованием.

Comment: @Mike систему я выбрал давно уже - Windows, пишу на WinApi. Просто интересно стало, можно ли своё, не WinApi-шное окно сделать на `с++` или `c`(без `Gdi`, и вообще без подключения `Windows.h`)

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик что значит "своё"? Если вы в Windows, то все рисует Windows, и пользоваться Вы будете в принципе ее функциями (типа CreateWindow())

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, я думал, что можно перехватывать данные от оборудования(что-то, типо очень низкоуровневого хука, или что-то такого), и работать уже с нетронутыми  данными. И, аналогично отправлять их, также напрямую к оборудованию.

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик Без GDI можно на OpenGL к примеру. А вот без Windows.h полностью свое перекрывающее/перекрываемое окно никак не получится. Оконная система крепко в ядро зашита.

Comment: @Cerbo, то есть, для таких дел - ассемблер, к примеру(и выполнять программу на нём,как я уже понял, не в Windows, а....А как?)

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик Да никак, основная функция ядра - разделение ресурсов, с прикладного уровня оно не позволит вам ничего сделать. Хоть на асме, хоть на чем пишите, от языка не зависит.

Comment: @Cerbo, да это я понял, а если писать на уровне, не знаю, загрузчика? То есть запускать не из-под оси

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик: А зачем вам? Вы решаете какую-то реальную проблему? В любом случае, ОС берёт на себя много задач, и если вы нарисуете своё окно прямо в видеопамяти, оно не будет взаимодействовать ни с мышью/клавиатурой, ни с другими окнами. Кроме того, ОС не будет знать, что у вас нарисовано окно, и затрёт его при первой же перерисовке экрана. Вам придётся реализовать оконный менеджер с нуля и подменять существующий. Это работы на несколько лет. Оно вам точно надо?

Comment: @VladD, воу, воу, мне всего лишь стало интересно, и я решил спросить об этом здесь. СПАСИБО ЗА ОТВЕТЫ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом по себе C/C++ таких возможностей нет - языки высокого уровня предполагают некоторый уровень абстрагирования от оборудования (в разных языках разный уровень, например, в Pascal уровень абстрагирования выше).
Эти возможности предоставляет операционная система, если она есть.
Если операционной системы нет или пишется код нижнего уровня (например, драйвера), то работа с оборудованием обычно строится примерно так.

Есть контроллер некоего устройства (например, клавиатуры). У этого контроллера имеется набор регистров с помощью которых он настраивается на нужный режим работы и посредством которых производится взаимодействие с контроллером. Эти регистры отображаются по каким-то известным адресам в памяти процессора и для доступа к регистрам используются эти адреса (еще бывает отдельное адресное пространство для этих целей: порты). Например:

```
#define pREG_UART1_BAUD (volatile unsigned long *)0xFFFF000C
*pREG_UART1_BAUD = 115200;
```

Детали зависят от контроллера и описываются в его документации.

Если хочется погрузиться на самый нижний уровень, можно почитать о программировании микроконтроллеров (на русском есть книги про PIC, AVR, ARM). Там нет операционных систем (по крайней мере, в привычном понимании) и вся работа производится напрямую.

Answer (score 3):

В С++ есть доступ к оборудованию только в виде чтения/записи `volatile` переменных.
Практически все компиляторы имеют средства (интринсики) для работы с аппаратными портами, и прочими средствами целевой платформы.

Однако всё это доступно только на уровне операционной системы (драйвера и сама ОС).
Для пользовательских приложений в Windows ничего такого не доступно.

Другими словами, если Вы пишете ОС или драйвер, то да, Вы можете работать с видеопамятью. Из обычного приложения - нет, потому что ОС такое запрещает.

Comment: А что за kernel mode? Это всё тоже в рамках ОС?

Comment: понял, буду знать

Comment: Если точнее, не только из ядра, драйвер может по своей воле расшарить ресурсы на прикладной уровень.